# How to Animate a Gradient Background that includes all html colors using css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, background, gradient

I have an HTML box, where a gradient background color animates. Gradient background includes 3 colors now. But I want to include all available colors.

How can we do that?

This is how I am doing right now.

```
background: linear-gradient(57deg, #fdd266, #c33c7a, #595ba8);
background-size: 600% 600%;
-webkit-animation: AnimationName 30s ease infinite;
-moz-animation: AnimationName 30s ease infinite;
animation: AnimationName 30s ease infinite;
height: 140px;
border-bottom: none;
```

Comment: Why is this tagged for javascript and jquery?

Comment: Could you explain what 'all available colors' means? Do you mean all RGB which would give 256*256*256 - rather a lot! Perhaps consider just merging between the main rainbow colors might do instead? Or are you wanting to use Javascript to literally go through the lot?

Comment: @Kinglish Because I think only CSS can't do that or may be I have no idea if that can be done with CSS only.

Comment: @AHaworth Yes that's correct 'All available colors' means all colors. I don't if this can be done with CSS only but I guess javascript can do that. But I don't know how?

Comment: Please add the code you have so far in your question. In particular your animation as I can’t work out what you want it to look like. Also, what order are the colors to appear in?

Comment: @AHaworth no specific order is required. I just want a gradient background with all colors. I have no other codes except what I mentioned in my question.

Comment: How do you want the animation? e.g. scrolling upwards continuously or... One problem is that you can have a whole viewport of almost the same color and then the next one is only a slight variation on that and so on so it's pretty visually boring.

Comment: @AHaworth color should continuously scroll at 57deg.  Its my client, he want it anyhow.

Comment: There is so little contrast within a viewport that the angle is unnoticeable until you get the inevitable sudden jump to the next set. Trying to show nearly 17 million colors just doesn’t produce anything a human can sensibly detect. I wonder if the client and you are talking about the same ‘all colors’. Show them just one viewports worth r and g at 0 and b from 0 to 255. It’s very unimpressive.

Comment: @AHaworth Thank you, man! I fixed it by adding a few color codes manually. in linear-gradient.

Comment: Which is by no means gibing 'eveery color' - but is a lot more sensible!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try as below

```css
.box {
    
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
    
    
    background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #fdd266, #c33c7a, #595ba8);
    background-size: 400% 400%;
    animation: gradient 15s ease infinite;
    height: 9rem;
    width:9rem;
    
}

@keyframes gradient {
    0% {
        background-position: 0% 50%;
    }
    50% {
        background-position: 100% 50%;
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 0% 50%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    here is your box
</div>
```

Comment: this is only 3 color gradient. I want all colors.